# Programa con try y catches JAVA

Tags: java, excepciones

Estoy haciendo un programa con excepciones, pero quiero que para los numeradores y denominadores quiero que los haga cada uno y si tiene el excepcion corregir el numerador o denominador que esta mal

```
package Unidad5.Excepciones;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class MultiplesExcepciones {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean fincaptura = true;
        int numerador = 0, denominador = 0;
        float valores[] = new float[6];
        do{
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Introduzca un numerador entero: ");
                numerador = in.nextInt();
                fincaptura=false;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.err.println("Atrapar una excepcion en tiempo de ejecucion desconocida");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Atrapar una excepcion desconocida");
            }
        } while (fincaptura == true);
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Introduzca un denominador entero: ");
                denominador = in.nextInt();
                fincaptura=false;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.err.println("Atrapar una excepcion en tiempo de ejecucion desconocida");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Atrapar una excepcion desconocida");
            }
        } while (fincaptura == true);
        do {
            try {
                float resultado = numerador / denominador;
                fincaptura = false;
                System.out.printf("\nResultado: %d/%d=%.2f\n", numerador, denominador, resultado);
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.err.println("Ocurrio un error aritmetico/div by Zero");
            }
        } while (fincaptura == true);
        do {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <= valores.length; i++) {
                    valores[1] = (float) (101.0 * Math.random());
                    System.out.format("valor %d = %.2f\n", i, valores[i]);
                }
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.err.println("Se excedio de los limites del arreglo");
            }
        } while (fincaptura == true);
        }while(fincaptura==true);
    }
}
```

Aqui intento poner los try y catch en cada uno pero me compila mal, solamente me aparecen las excepciones y quiero que si un denominador este mal quiero corregir ese denominador nada mas

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que cuando un numerador es correctamente ingresado como entero el valor de `fincaptura` se convierte en `false` ,es por esa razón que el bucle del `denominador` no se llega a cumplir,despues de recibir un numerador correcto debes cambiar el valor de `fincaptura` de `false` a `true` y asi podras evaluar los correctos ingreso tanto en numerador con denominador

```
do {
            try {
                System.out.print("Introduzca un numerador entero: ");
                numerador = in.nextInt();
                fincaptura=false;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.err.println("Atrapar una excepcion en tiempo de ejecucion desconocida");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Atrapar una excepcion desconocida");
            }
        } while (fincaptura == true);

        
        fincaptura=true;// agregar


        do {
            try {

                System.out.print("Introduzca un denominador entero: ");
                denominador = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("el valor es "+ denominador);
                fincaptura=false;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.err.println("Atrapar una excepcion en tiempo de ejecucion desconocida");
                in.nextLine();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Atrapar una excepcion desconocida");
            }
        } while (fincaptura == true);
```